# Angular2 expressions not rendering

Tags: templates, typescript, expression, render, angular

I'm having trouble getting expressions to render in Angular2.

For instance, I have something like the example below, but the `{{profile.name}}` renders nothing.

However it's not just when accessing something off the component instance. No matter what I put in the expression, it won't render (e.g. `{{1 + 2}}`). And what's weirder, it deletes all the content of the DOM element the expression is contained in.

```
import { Component, View } from 'angular2/core'

@Component({
  selector: 'my-component'
})
@View({
  template: `
  <div class="user">
    {{profile.name}}
  </div>
  `
})
export class MyComponent {
  profile

  constructor() {
    this.profile = {
      name: 'John Smith'
    }
  }
}
```

Not sure what I'm missing. Any help would be much appreciated!

**EDIT**

So I have done some further testing, and have found the issue only occurs when I am using `<router-outlet>`. So I have something that looks like this (apologies for the amount of code)

**app.ts**

```
import { View, Component } from 'angular2/core'
import { RouteConfig, RouterOutlet } from 'angular2/router'

import { Home } from './home'

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app'
})
@View({
  template: '<router-outlet></router-outlet>',
  directives: [RouterOutlet]
})
@RouteConfig([
  { path: '/', redirectTo: ['/Home'] },
  { path: '/home', as: 'Home', component: Home }
])
export class App {
  constructor(public router: Router) {}
}
```

**home.ts**

```
import { Component, View } from 'angular2/core'

@Component({
  selector: 'home',
})
@View({
  template: '{{name}}'
})
export class Home {
  name:string = 'John Smith'
}
```

Comment: Are you specifying this component in the parent classes that uses it?  I.e., does it have `directives: [MyComponent]`?

Comment: Any error messages? This is correct in isolation

Comment: I've done some further testing, and have found the problem seems to only occur when I'm using the <router-outlet> directive. Any directives loaded via that borks out when using expressions... I'm still stumped. I'll update the example.

Answer (score 5):

I had similar problem. I had my Angular2 libraries defined in wrong order.

Defining libraries in this order helped:

```
<!-- Keep these first!!! -->
<script src="~/node_modules/es6-shim/es6-shim.js"></script>
<script src="~/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system-polyfills.js"></script>

<script src="~/node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>
<script src="~/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.js"></script>
...
```

Place of the system-polyfills seems to be important!

Comment: Holy crap! Thanks for this answer! I'm really curious on how you managed to figure this out.

Comment: Yes...I'm impressed you got this.  Does it just seem that Angular 2 can be a bit brittle with all of the "ceremony" that you have to go through - including making sure certain js files are loaded in a given order???

Answer (score 1):

I think that Mark points the problem out in his comment! To develop a bit more. In fact, you need to explicitly define the components (and directives) you want to use in another component (except the ones from `angular/core`) into the `directives` attribute.

Here is the way you would use your `MyComponent` component into another one:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <my-component></my-component>
  `,
  directives: [ MyComponent ]
})
export class AppComponent {
  (...)
}
```

I tested this with your `MyComponent` class and it works.

Hope it helps you,
Thierry

Comment: I've done some further testing, and have found the problem seems to only occur when I'm using the `<router-outlet>` directive. Any directives loaded via that borks out when using expressions... I'm still stumped. I'll update the example.

Answer (score 1):

That seems to happen if you don't include zone.js. Adding an `import "zone.js/lib/browser/zone-microtask";` before bootstrapping Angular fixed the problem for me.

Comment: Thanks @xod This should be in angular.io tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem where, using the router and router-outlet, it would not render my page as soon as I added *ngFor or *ngIf-like statements.
Expressions with mustaches worked, however. This is for Angular v2.0.0-rc.6.

There were absolutely no error messages, simply an empty page, which seems cruel (yes, I'm talking to you, Angular team ;-) ).

Being relatively new to Angular2, it took me a while to figure out that I was missing the [CommonModule](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/CommonModule-class.html):

```
import { CommonModule }      from "@angular/common";

@NgModule({
imports: [
    CommonModule,
    yourRouting
],
declarations: [
    YourComponent
]
})

export class OrderModule {
}
```

I figured it out by going over the [Angular routing tutorial](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html) and their [live demo](https://angular.io/resources/live-examples/router/ts/plnkr.html) and comparing their setup to mine.

Maybe that helps someone down the line.

Comment: Thank yuh bro...This helped me!