# ngOnInit not triggered on page load

Tags: angular

I have a component called `CarComponent` which can be found at `/car`.

When I navigate to `http://localhost:4200/car`, it goes to the correct route and shows my `CarComponent` template, but my component's `ngOnInit` function is not invoked. Here's my component code:

```
// src/app/+car/car.component.ts

import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, HTTP_PROVIDERS } from '@angular/http';

@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'app-car',
  templateUrl: 'car.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['car.component.css']
})

export class CarComponent implements OnInit {
  cars: any;

  constructor(public http: Http) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log('init');
    this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/api/cars.json')
      .subscribe(response => this.cars = response.json());
  }

}
```

Here are a couple other files if it helps:

```
// src/app/dream-cars.component.ts

import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { CarComponent } from './+car';
import { Routes , ROUTER_DIRECTIVES} from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'dream-cars-app',
  templateUrl: 'dream-cars.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['dream-cars.component.css'],
  directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES]
})
@Routes([
  {path: '/car', component: CarComponent}
])
export class DreamCarsAppComponent {
  title = 'Dream Cars';
}
```

-

```
<!-- src/app/dream-cars.component.html -->

<h1>{{title}}</h1>

<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a [routerLink]="['/']">Home</a></li>
    <li><a [routerLink]="['/car']">Cars</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

How do I get `ngOnInit` (or any function, I don't care) to get invoked when I load the page?

By the way, it also doesn't get invoked when I click my link to `/car`. When I click the link, it goes to the correct route, but doesn't call `ngOnInit`. Only if I click the link *twice* does it work as desired.

Again, `ngOnInit` isn't the important thing to me. I just want my component to make an API call when the page loads.

Comment: What browser and what Angular version?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Chrome and Angular 2.0.0-rc.1.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I guess you're right. Luckily I found the solution in another SO answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This turned out to be the solution: [Angular2 expressions not rendering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34625205/angular2-expressions-not-rendering/35058096#35058096)

I had to change my script inclusion order from this

```
<script src="vendor/es6-shim/es6-shim.js"></script>
<script src="vendor/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js"></script>
<script src="vendor/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
<script src="vendor/systemjs/dist/system-polyfills.js"></script>
<script src="vendor/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
```

to this

```
<script src="vendor/es6-shim/es6-shim.js"></script>
<script src="vendor/systemjs/dist/system-polyfills.js"></script>
<script src="vendor/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js"></script>
<script src="vendor/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
<script src="vendor/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
```

I restarted my server and it worked.